# Обсобление вставных конструкций

Tags: пунктуация

Как лучше обособить вставную конструкцию "до одной недели" - скобками или тире? Просто такое ощущение, что в первом случае предложение получается перегружено скобками - или это нормально?

В данный момент склад наполнен наиболее ходовой продукцией (поворотная арматура, поршневые пневмоприводы, позиционеры и другое навесное оборудование) и запчастями для обеспечения минимальных сроков поставки (до одной недели) и оперативного реагирования на сервисные обращения наших заказчиков со всей страны.

Или:

В данный момент склад наполнен наиболее ходовой продукцией (поворотная арматура, поршневые пневмоприводы, позиционеры и другое навесное оборудование) и запчастями для обеспечения минимальных сроков поставки — до одной недели — и оперативного реагирования на сервисные обращения наших заказчиков со всей страны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Желательно оставить скобки, они лучше подчеркивают добавочный характер информации в обоих случаях.